# IIS7 Handler - How to get page content returned?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, handler

I've got a simple IIS7 Handler that inserts some text on the page.  What I'm looking to do is get the normal page content that would be returned on a request.  I've reviewed all the HttpContext methods but was not able to find anything.  I can do:

```
context.Response.Write("<H1>This is a Test.</H1>");
```

This replaces the content that would normally load.  How can I get the normal content loaded into a variable and then display that underneath this?

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

NOTE: I'm doing this through a handler, not a standard ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to use is HttpResponse.Filter, as demonstrated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx